# узнать какие есть столбцы в dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно узнать какие столбцы есть в dataGridView

Comment: Какой именно компонент используется: [DataGrid](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.7.2) или [DataGridView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.7.2)? И как данные были занесены в этот грид?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Petrov DataGridView

Comment: Свойство [Columns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_Columns)

Answer (score 0):

У DataGridView есть множество свойств. Например `dataGridView.Columns` возвращает все столбцы, а `dataGridView.Rows` - все строки. И вообще, перед тем как задавать такие вопросы, следуют погуглить информацию в интернете...

- [DataGridView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.7.2)